# Convert script return date to php date

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to export a report in excel with a date in UTC format. When I export it, it shows a script in excel but what I want is to show only the date in php format ('Y-m-d'). How can I convert this script date into a PHP date?

```
<?php 

$tempDate = datefun($cValue->datedata,$cValue->timedata);
$finalDateValue = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tempDate));

function datefun($dateValue,$timeValue) {

        $d_t = explode("-",$dateValue);
        $yr = $d_t[0];$mn = $d_t[1]-1;$dt = $d_t[2];

        $t_t = explode(":",$timeValue);
        $hr = $t_t[0];$min = $t_t[1];$sec = $t_t[2];// dt.getTime() - 1*60*60*1000
        $dat_call = "<script>var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(".$yr.",".$mn.",".$dt.",".$hr.",".$min.",".$sec."));
            var today = new Date(Date.UTC(".$yr.",".$mn.",".$dt.",".$hr.",".$min.",".$sec."));
            Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
            var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
            return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
            }
            offst = -1 * today.stdTimezoneOffset();
            var test = dt.getTime();
            if(getTimezoneName()=='Europe/London')
            {
                var date = new Date(test);
            }
            else{
                var date = new Date(test+ (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)+(offst/60)*60*60*1000);
            }
            hhr=checkTime(date.getHours());
            m=checkTime(date.getMinutes());
            s=checkTime(date.getSeconds());
            ddt=checkTime(date.getDate());
            mnt=checkTime((date.getMonth()+1));

            fin = date.getFullYear()+'-'+mnt+'-'+ddt;

            document.write(fin)

            function checkTime(i)
            {
            if (i<10)
              {
              i='0' + i;
              }
            return i;
            }
            function getTimezoneName() {
                tmSummer = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                so = -1 * tmSummer.getTimezoneOffset();
                tmWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                wo = -1 * tmWinter.getTimezoneOffset();
                if (-660 == so && -660 == wo) return 'Pacific/Midway';
                if (-600 == so && -600 == wo) return 'Pacific/Tahiti';
                if (-570 == so && -570 == wo) return 'Pacific/Marquesas';
                if (-540 == so && -600 == wo) return 'America/Adak';
                if (-540 == so && -540 == wo) return 'Pacific/Gambier';
                if (-480 == so && -540 == wo) return 'US/Alaska';
                if (-480 == so && -480 == wo) return 'Pacific/Pitcairn';
                if (-420 == so && -480 == wo) return 'US/Pacific';
                if (-420 == so && -420 == wo) return 'US/Arizona';
                if (-360 == so && -420 == wo) return 'US/Mountain';
                if (-360 == so && -360 == wo) return 'America/Guatemala';
                if (-360 == so && -300 == wo) return 'Pacific/Easter';
                if (-300 == so && -360 == wo) return 'US/Central';
                if (-300 == so && -300 == wo) return 'America/Bogota';
                if (-240 == so && -300 == wo) return 'US/Eastern';
                if (-240 == so && -240 == wo) return 'America/Caracas';
                if (-240 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Santiago';
                if (-180 == so && -240 == wo) return 'Canada/Atlantic';
                if (-180 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Montevideo';
                if (-180 == so && -120 == wo) return 'America/Sao_Paulo';
                if (-150 == so && -210 == wo) return 'America/St_Johns';
                if (-120 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Godthab';
                if (-120 == so && -120 == wo) return 'America/Noronha';
                if (-60 == so && -60 == wo) return 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde';
                if (0 == so && -60 == wo) return 'Atlantic/Azores';
                if (0 == so && 0 == wo) return 'Africa/Casablanca';
                if (60 == so && 0 == wo) return 'Europe/London';
                if (60 == so && 60 == wo) return 'Africa/Algiers';
                if (60 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Africa/Windhoek';
                if (120 == so && 60 == wo) return 'Europe/Amsterdam';
                if (120 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Africa/Harare';
                if (180 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Europe/Athens';
                if (180 == so && 180 == wo) return 'Africa/Nairobi';
                if (240 == so && 180 == wo) return 'Europe/Moscow';
                if (240 == so && 240 == wo) return 'Asia/Dubai';
                if (270 == so && 210 == wo) return 'Asia/Tehran';
                if (270 == so && 270 == wo) return 'Asia/Kabul';
                if (300 == so && 240 == wo) return 'Asia/Baku';
                if (300 == so && 300 == wo) return 'Asia/Karachi';
                if (330 == so && 330 == wo) return 'Asia/Calcutta';
                if (345 == so && 345 == wo) return 'Asia/Katmandu';
                if (360 == so && 300 == wo) return 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';
                if (360 == so && 360 == wo) return 'Asia/Colombo';
                if (390 == so && 390 == wo) return 'Asia/Rangoon';
                if (420 == so && 360 == wo) return 'Asia/Almaty';
                if (420 == so && 420 == wo) return 'Asia/Bangkok';
                if (480 == so && 420 == wo) return 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk';
                if (480 == so && 480 == wo) return 'Australia/Perth';
                if (540 == so && 480 == wo) return 'Asia/Irkutsk';
                if (540 == so && 540 == wo) return 'Asia/Tokyo';
                if (570 == so && 570 == wo) return 'Australia/Darwin';
                if (570 == so && 630 == wo) return 'Australia/Adelaide';
                if (600 == so && 540 == wo) return 'Asia/Yakutsk';
                if (600 == so && 600 == wo) return 'Australia/Brisbane';
                if (600 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Australia/Sydney';
                if (630 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Australia/Lord_Howe';
                if (660 == so && 600 == wo) return 'Asia/Vladivostok';
                if (660 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Pacific/Guadalcanal';
                if (690 == so && 690 == wo) return 'Pacific/Norfolk';
                if (720 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Asia/Magadan';
                if (720 == so && 720 == wo) return 'Pacific/Fiji';
                if (720 == so && 780 == wo) return 'Pacific/Auckland';
                if (765 == so && 825 == wo) return 'Pacific/Chatham';
                if (780 == so && 780 == wo) return 'Pacific/Enderbury'
                if (840 == so && 840 == wo) return 'Pacific/Kiritimati';
                return;
            }

            </script>";
        return $dat_call;
        exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: when i try to export it show date column in excel like    <script>var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,1,15,07,10,55));
   var today = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,1,15,07,10,55));
   Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
   var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
   var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6

Comment: but i want to show like 2016-01-15

Comment: `return $dat_call();`

Comment: if i use return $dat_call(); it show error like    Fatal error:  Call to undefined function <script>var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,1,15,12,02,42));
   var today = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,1,15,12,02,42));
   Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
   var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
   var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
   return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
   }
   offst = -1 * today.stdTimezoneOffset();
   var test = dt.getTime();
   ..........................